# Java Do-While Try-Catch exception handling loop error and symbol: variable error

Tags: java, exception, try-catch, do-while

Fixed(new working code below). I am running into a little problem that I cannot figure out. The first do-while works as intended and will go through until it gets a valid input. However the Second loop will end whether I input a valid or invalid #. And then in the 3rd loop, I get **2 errors:**

I am not sure why I am getting these errors when the variables have already been declared?

A little explanation on what I am trying to do:

I am supposed to get 3 inputs: years of experience (yearsexp), performance (performance) and a random int generated between 1-10(level). The program will ask the user for their experience if it is between 3-11 they are qualified. If not, it will tell them they are not qualified and ask to re-enter a value. Same thing with performance. If they enter a number less than or equal to 11 it will procede to generate the random int (level) at which point level will be used to asses their bonus.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;     

class assignment {   
     public static void main( String args[]){
      //
      int bonus;
      int x;
      //
      Random rand = new Random();
      //
      Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner for name
      System.out.println("Enter your name: "); // ask for name
      String name = input.nextLine(); // assign name to variable
      System.out.println( name ); // output name 
      // 
      Scanner input2 = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner for yearsexp
      System.out.println(name + ", Enter the years of your experience: "); // ask for yearsexp
      int yearsexp = 0 ; 
      int performance = 0;

      do 
      {
      yearsexp = input2.nextInt(); // assign yearsexp to variable
      System.out.println( yearsexp); // out yearsexp
      try
         {
         if (yearsexp >= 3 && yearsexp <24)// acceptable critera
            {
            System.out.println("You are qualified");// output
            x=2; // x = 2 to close do while
            }
         else
         {
         throw new Exception ();
         }
         }
       catch (Exception e1)
         {
         System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number! Try again..."); //output is unacceptable
         x=1;
         }
         }
         while (x==1); // keep do loop going if exception e 
      //
      Scanner input3 = new Scanner(System.in); // scanner for performance
      System.out.println(name + ", Enter the performance: "); // ask for performance
      //
      do 
      {
      performance = input3.nextInt(); // assign performance to variable
      System.out.println( performance ) ; // output performance
      try
         {
         if (performance <= 11) // acceptable criteria
            {
            System.out.println("You are qualified"); //output
            x=2; // x = 2 to close do while
            }
         else
            {
            throw new Exception ();
            }
         }
      catch (Exception e2)
         {
         System.out.println("You have entered an invalid number! Try again..."); //output if criteria is unacceptable
         x=1;
         }
         }
         while (x==1); // keep doing while
      //
      int level = rand.nextInt(11); // fix to be between 1-10 to not include 0
      System.out.println("Random Level: " + level);  //output level
      //
     do
      {
      try
         {
         if (level >=5 && level <=8)//acceptable criteria
            {
            System.out.println("Expected Bonus: $5000.00"); //output
            x = 2; // x = 2 to close while
            }
         else if (level <= 4) // else if criteria
            {
            bonus = 5000 * yearsexp * performance * level; // calculate bonus if level <=4
            System.out.println(bonus); // output bonus
            if (bonus < 15000)
               {
               System.out.println(bonus);
               }
            else if (bonus > 15000)
               {
               System.out.println("Your bonus is TBL");
               {
               x = 2; // x = 2 to close while
               }
             }
            }
           } 
        catch (Exception e3)
            {
            System.out.println("You do not get a bonus"); //output if criteria is unacceptable
            x=1;
            }
            }
            while (x==1); 

       }
  }
```

Comment: You do not need to declare multiple instances of a `Scanner` that uses `System.in`.  You can keep using the same one.

Comment: You're declaring `yearsexp` and 'performance' inside of try blocks.  This causes the try block to be that variable's [scope](https://www.baeldung.com/java-variable-scope), and the variables don't exist outside of that scope.  You need to declare the variables at outside of the try blocks, so that they're visible inside all of the try blocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you're getting those compilation errors is because `performance` is only scoped to the `try` statement of your second do/while loop.

If you need 'knowledge' of the value of `performance` and `yearsexp` to propagate from the second do/while loop to the third, you need to declare the variables before both loops, such that they're scoped to be visible to both.

To go into a bit more detail,

```
if (foo()) {
  int myValue = 1;
}
System.out.println(myValue);
```

doesn't work because the `myValue` variable is scoped to the if statement, meaning as far as the println statement is concerned, it doesn't exist. The same is also true for `for`, `while`, `do/while` and `try/catch` statements.

```
try {
  String a = "hello";
} catch (Exception e) {
}

System.out.println(a);
```

Doesn't work either.

Comment: Also his `yearsexp` is not scoped correctly either.